# GET cart.js empty | shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify

I am developing a Shopify store using their API. But I have hit a rather large snag that seems simple, but I can't fix.

I have successfully viewed all products and their variants. I can also add a product/variant to the cart. It is "successful" because I am getting a status of 200 AND I can see what products are getting added with my Shopify account. Everything on that end is working.

When I call the cart with GET request I am able to see the cart, but it is completely empty (item_count: 0). I have tried adding different products/variants. It is always empty.

Am I missing something? Do I need to call the cart another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to create your own add to cart function for a standard shopify store? Please provide some context and sample code.

Comment: My guess is that you're not hitting the add-to-cart endpoint correctly.  Make sure that you're posting to `/cart/add.js` and that the data contains (at minimum) a valid variant ID.  (Using the serialized form is better, as that ensures any properties set by various apps get through as well). I've hand-written enough Shopify ajax calls that I've forgotten the 'post' on occasion, and that returns a 200 (Yup! Got the page!) without doing anything, leaving me wondering what's "taking things out" for a few moments.

Comment: After hitting the add-to-cart endpoint, you can also manually navigate to [yourstore]/cart.js to see what's currently in your cart.  I usually have a separate tab open to constantly refresh the raw data view when testing.  A browser extension like JSONview is very much your friend for this if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 0):

When you GET cart.js, and your item count is zero, it means you failed to place anything in the cart. When you do place items in the cart, and you validate they are actually in the cart, and you do a GET on cart.js, if that call is still empty, then you are really really unlucky and are probably just making a really dumb mistake in your GET call.

Comment: I have same problem, and what's stranger is that if I check /cart directly I get items inside but /cart.js is returning empty list still.

Comment: There are many ways to POST data to the cart endpoint and get back a valid cart and many mnay more ways to do it in an invalid way. Since you can see items in the cart, if your GET request is correct, you will see them, not item_count=0. Check your GET request very carefully. You likely have an issue with it. Inspect with a tool like Charles. Often the simplest things can defeat the best intentions on the supposedly easiest things.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with GET request(Can be verified by visiting that URL directly in browser where I still see empty list).

What it appears that is happening here is that Shopify has issues with invalidating /cart.js request when cart is updated, because I can see in headers (cf-cache-status:HIT) that /cart.js is always returnes cached version from Cloud Flare.

Comment: Also this issue appeared in last 2 days. Before that everything was working as normal.

Comment: Super! So carry on. You apparently have no issue that you can do anything about.